# Windows XP doesnt start, it freezes at boot logo

Tags: windows, boot, freeze, safe-mode

The progress bar at windows logo doesnt work and disk does nothing, i once left it for a few hours and screen has not changed.

I tried this from recovery console

```
bootcfg /scan
fixmbr
fixboot
chkdsk /r
```

Nothing has changed, any ideas?

Windows recovery mode(i dont know how its called in english) works and i can even use internet from it, any way to make it the default one(now i have to always manually select it after pressing f8)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to boot to the Last Known Good Configuration.

If by recovery mode you mean Safe mode, then if this is working then you can use System Restore to rollback your system to a time before this problem started.

The fact that Safe mode is working means that a third-party program is getting stuck during the boot. You can use [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to turn of startup programs until you find the guilty one, and also you can take a backup of the current state that you can later easily restore.

Control Panel / Add/Remove programs can tell you the date of installation. It might be that the date of an installation corresponds with the time the problem started, and so pinpoint the problem.

**EDIT**

A free product that specializes in boot problems is [Paragon's Rescue Kit 9.0 Express](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-express/):

> Boot Corrector option resolves various
>   problems you may encounter during the
>   system boot process. These problems
>   may be caused by program errors, user
>   mistakes, or become the results of
>   boot virus activity. Boot Corrector
>   allows you to cure the majority of
>   boot problems for Windows Operating
>   System and gives you access to your
>   data!

You might give it a try.

Comment: The only things that could interfere with the *boot process* would be device drivers. Third party programs usually don't hook themselves there so removing startup programs very likely won't help.

Comment: The question is whether "recovery mode" is Recovery Console or Safe mode. My answer assumed it's Safe mode. However, if Safe mode doesn't work then the problem is inside Windows. In this case one can do a debug boot and maybe succeed in seeing on which driver it hangs. If not, repair install is the last resort (before a full install).

Comment: @01: Which part of my advice worked for you?

Comment: Today, when restarting my Windows Vista computer, the computer stopped working at the "Welcome"-screen. The blue circle just spun on and on next to welcome. I booted in Safe-mode with networking and found an answer on the Internet. The Windows Event Log service was the culprit.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Very interesting. Could you please post a pointer to that article?